# setting images to EXCLUDE from magento gallery

Tags: php, sql, magento, import, gallery

I have imported about 2000 products into Magento. They all only have one image, but the gallery thumbnail still shows up on the product page.

From my understanding, to have them not show the extra thumbnail, the images should have a property of EXCLUDE.

After some research i found the table where this setting apparently resides.  However instead of 2000 records, it holds only about 160.  I have ran the sql script to set all the values to "1"

UPDATE`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = '1' WHERE `disabled` = '0';

This does effect the table and does what its supposed to, but Magento is still showing the thumbnail in the gallery.  My main clue is the fact that there is only 160 records instead of 2000

any ideas what is going on here and how i can make it so if the item only has one image not to show the thumbnail gallery